# Mercurial repository architecture

Tags: version-control, mercurial

We have 3 central mercurial repositories, one is the stable version that is the code that went out in the last release, and the other two are dev repositories.

Most of the time I will be working on one of the dev repositories (but occasionally may have to make a change to the other dev repository or to the stable repository).

Do I create three directories on my local machine and create a mercurial repository in each, or is there a way in which I can work from a single repository on my machine and synchronise my local repository with the appropriate central one?

What's the best approach here?

Comment: What's the difference between the two dev repositories?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen - They are on different length development cycles with the minor version releases to the one getting merged into the next major version in dev on the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 directories is the best approach.

You *can* work with a single local clone, but you will have quite a bit of work ensuring you don't push things to a repository that you're not supposed to.

Having 3 distinct local folders makes it easier to ensure you're working in the right one, and ensure you're not accidentally pushing to the production/release repository.